# AWS CDK app doesn't start a new EC2 instance during redeployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

I have an AWS CDK application that I often redeploy through a GitHub action. The application is an ECS service running on an autoscaling group of EC2 instances.

My service is set up to require 8192 CPU credits and 30,000 MB of RAM, so it should fit in a t2.2xlarge EC2 instance.

When I redeploy the app I'd expect AWS to check the available EC2 instances, see that there's not enough resources in the existing one, start a new EC2 instance, mount the service there and terminate the obsolete instance. Instead of that, I get the following error:

`service was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements. The closest matching container-instance has insufficient CPU units available`

I don't want ECS to place the service into the old instance: I want it to be placed into a new one.

This is my CDK setup:

```py
cluster = ecs.Cluster(
    self,
    "cluster",
    vpc=vpc,
)

task_definition = ecs.Ec2TaskDefinition(
    self,
    "taskDefinition",
    execution_role=role,
)

task_definition.add_container(
    "container",
    image=docker_image,
    port_mappings=[port_mapping],
    cpu=8192,
    memory_limit_mib=30_000,
)

autoscaling_group = autoscaling.AutoScalingGroup(
    self,
    "autoscalingGroup",
    instance_type=ec2.InstanceType("t2.2xlarge"),
    min_capacity=1,
    max_capacity=2,
    update_policy=autoscaling.UpdatePolicy.rolling_update(
        min_instances_in_service=1,
    ),
)

capacity_provider = ecs.AsgCapacityProvider(
    self,
    "asgCapacityProvider",
    auto_scaling_group=autoscaling_group,
)

cluster.add_asg_capacity_provider(capacity_provider)

service = ecs.Ec2Service(
    self,
    "service",
    cluster=cluster,
    task_definition=task_definition,
)
```

And this is the final step of my GitHub action:

```bash
aws ecs \
    update-service \
    --cluster "${VAR_CLUSTER}" \
    --service "${VAR_SERVICE}" \
    --force-new-deployment
```

Comment: I was able to do something similar to what I wanted to: I set the number of desired instances to twice the number of minimum instances (in this case, 2) so EC2 would be forced to create a new instance each time I redeploy the application. Then, when ECS is forced to do a new deployment, it finds the new instance and places the service there. I also added an autoscaling policy based on CPU usage, so a few minutes later the cluster scales in and the obsolete instance is terminated. Sadly, this hack will fail if there's more than one instance active during redeployment.

Comment: I am in your exact situation. I do not understand why the hell this is so complex. 
The only solution I was able to find is to have a 'spare' machine i.e. increase the min number of instances (via min_capacity) to be one more than what I really need.

I would like to see if it's possible to react to the 'error' we see from ECS complaining via a lambda, to temporarely increase the number of machines in the cluster. But even if this is possible, this is completely defeating the point of having an ASG.

Let me know if you found a solution in the meantime.

Answer (score 2):

`t2.2xlarge` instances have `8 vCPUs` which translates to `8192 CPU units` and is completely equal with the task definition requirements of your container. In order for the EC2 instance to host your containers, it will require a fraction of its CPUs to run the underlying OS and Daemons required by ECS. To solve your problem you have two options:

- Decrease the CPU you'd like to allocate on the container instance to `7 vCPUs` or anything smaller.
- If you really need 8 vCPUs then search for an instance that offers a higher number of vCPUs than what your application requires.

Comment: This is not the issue: you don't need to reserve CPU credits for the OS like you do with RAM. Also, the service is already running on a t2.2xlarge. But I tested it anyways and it didn't work.

Comment: Check in the ECS console - how much CPU units does the instance show as available?